# Using the implicit function theorem to solve for two of four variables in the system of two equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-function-theorem

> Show that there are positive numbers $p$ and $q$ and unique functions $u$ and $v$ from the interval $(-1-p, -1+p)$ into the interval $(1-q, 1+q)$ satisfying
> $$xe^{u(x)} +u(x)e^{v(x)}=0=xe^{v(x)} +v(x)e^{u(x)}$$
> for all $x$ in the interval  $(-1-p, -1+p)$ with $u(-1)=1=v(-1)$.

#### Progress

The first step is to take the Jacobian, which I did, but that didn't do much for me. The Jacobian was $$(x^{2}+1 -uv)e^{u+v}+x(e^{2u}+e^{2v})$$

Comment: Next step would be to show that the relevant determinant is nonzero (namely, the determinant made of partials with respect to $u$ and $v$, the variables you want to solve for). Can you add the result of your calculation of Jacobian to the question?

Comment: i got $(x^{2}+1 -uv)e^{u+v}+x(e^{2u}+e^{2v})$

Answer (score 0):

Taking derivatives of both equations with respect to $u,v$ and forming the Jacobian  led to   $$(x^{2}+1 -uv)e^{u+v}+x(e^{2u}+e^{2v})$$
We are told to look at a neighborhood of the point $x=-1$, $u=1$, $v=1$. At this point, the Jacobian evaluates to $-e^{2}$, which is nonzero. Therefore, the Implicit Function theorem applies: there is a neighborhood of $-1$ in which $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ are smooth functions with $u(-1)=1$, $v(-1)=1$.

Comment: thanks but i dont see how this answers the part about the intervals $(-1-p, -1+p)$ $(-1-q,-1+q)$